# Remove and extract minimum from Numpy ndarray along 3rd dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of shape `(3, 4, 3)` which represents an image of 3x4 pixels and with 3 color channels (the last index). My goal is to be left with a `(3, 4, 2)` array where each pixel has the lowest color channel removed. I could do a pixelwise iteration but this would be very time consuming. Using `np.argmin` I can easily extract the index of the minimum value, so that I know which color channel contains the minimum value for each pixel. However, I cannot find a clever way of indexing to remove these values so that I am left with a `(3, 4, 2)` array.

Additionally, I also tried to select the minimum values by using something like `array[:, :, indexMin)]` but was unable to get the desired array of shape `(3, 4)` that contains the minimum channel value for each pixel. I know there is a function `np.amin` for this, but it will give me a better understanding of Numpy arrays. A minimum example of my code structure is provided below:

```
import numpy as np

arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8],
       [9, 10, 11, 12]]
array = np.zeros((3, 4, 3))
array[:,:,0] = arr
array[:,:,1] = np.fliplr(arr)
array[:,:,2] = np.flipud(arr)
indexMin = np.argmin(array, axis=2)
```

Comment: do you need the order of the channels to be preserved otherwise? if not and if you can take the small runtime complexity hit, you could do this: `array.sort(axis=2); 
array[:,:,1:]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need arrays that broadcast correctly to the output shape you want. You can add the missing dimension back using [`np.expand_dims`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html):

```
index = np.expand_dims(np.argmin(array, axis=2), axis=2)
```

This makes it easy to set or extract the elements that you want to remove:

```
index = list(np.indices(array.shape, sparse=True))
index[-1] = np.expand_dims(np.argmin(array, axis=2), axis=2)
minima = array[tuple(index)]
```

[`np.indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) with `sparse=True` returns a set of ranges shaped to broadcast the index correctly in each dimension. A nicer alternative is to use [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html):

```
index = np.expand_dims(np.argmin(array, axis=2), axis=2)
minima = np.take_along_axis(array, index, axis=2)
```

You can use these results to create a mask, e.g. with [`np.put_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html):

```
mask = np.ones(array.shape, dtype=bool)
np.put_along_axis(mask, index, 0, axis=2)
```

Indexing the array with the mask gives you:

```
result = array[mask].reshape(*array.shape[:2], -1)
```

The reshape works because your pixels are stored in the last dimension, which should be contiguous in memory. That means that the mask removes one out of three elements correctly, and thus is ordered correctly in memory. That is not usual with masking operations.

Another alternative is to use [`np.delete`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) with a raveled array and [`np.ravel_multi_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html):

```
i = np.indices(array.shape[:2], sparse=True)
index = np.ravel_multi_index((*i, np.argmin(array, axis=2)), array.shape)
result = np.delete(array.ravel(), index).reshape(*array.shape[:2], -1)
```

Just for fun, you can use the fact that you only have three elements per pixel to create a full index of the elements you want to keep. The idea is that the sum of all three indices is `3`. Therefore, `3 - np.argmin(array, axis=2) - np.argmax(array, axis=2)` is the median element. If you stack the median and the max, you get an index similar to what `sort` gives you:

```
amax = np.argmax(array, axis=2)
amin = np.argmin(array, axis=2)
index = np.stack((np.clip(3 - (amin + amax), 0, 2), amax), axis=2)
result = np.take_along_axis(array, index, axis=2)
```

The call to [`np.clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) is necessary to handle the case where all elements are equal, in which case both `argmax` and `argmin` return zero.

**Timing**

Comparing the approaches:

```
def remove_min_indices(array):
    index = list(np.indices(array.shape, sparse=True))
    index[-1] = np.expand_dims(np.argmin(array, axis=2), axis=2)
    mask = np.ones(array.shape, dtype=bool)
    mask[tuple(index)] = False
    return array[mask].reshape(*array.shape[:2], -1)

def remove_min_put(array):
    mask = np.ones(array.shape, dtype=bool)
    np.put_along_axis(mask, np.expand_dims(np.argmin(array, axis=2), axis=2), 0, axis=2)
    return array[mask].reshape(*array.shape[:2], -1)

def remove_min_delete(array):
    i = np.indices(array.shape[:2], sparse=True)
    index = np.ravel_multi_index((*i, np.argmin(array, axis=2)), array.shape)
    return np.delete(array.ravel(), index).reshape(*array.shape[:2], -1)

def remove_min_sort_c(array):
    return np.sort(array, axis=2)[..., 1:]

def remove_min_sort_i(array):
    array.sort(axis=2)
    return array[..., 1:]

def remove_min_median(array):
    amax = np.argmax(array, axis=2)
    amin = np.argmin(array, axis=2)
    index = np.stack((np.clip(3 - (amin + amax), 0, 2), amax), axis=2)
    return np.take_along_axis(array, index, axis=2)
```

Tested for arrays made like `array = np.random.randint(10, size=(N, N, 3), dtype=np.uint8)` for `N` in `{100, 1K, 10K, 100K, 1M}`:

```
  N  |   IND   |   PUT   |   DEL   |   S_C   |   S_I   |   MED   |
-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
100  | 648. µs | 658. µs | 765. µs | 497. µs | 246. µs | 905. µs |
  1K | 67.9 ms | 68.1 ms | 85.7 ms | 51.7 ms | 24.0 ms | 123. ms |
 10K | 6.86 s  | 6.86 s  | 8.72 s  | 5.17 s  | 2.39 s  | 13.2 s  |
-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Times scale with `N^2`, as expected. Sorting returns a different result from the other approaches, but is clearly the most efficient. Masking with `put_along_axis` seems to be the more efficient approach for larger arrays, while raw indexing seems to be more efficient for smaller ones.

Comment: Great answer! `ndarray.sort()` would be slightly faster than `np.sort()`, probably just shaving off a copy.

Comment: @user228395. I added another very slow method

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot! Since `remove_min_sort_i()` is the fastest option, I implemented it as an exact copy of the code supplied in the answer but the following error is raised: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. I could only get it working by first sorting using `array.sort()` and then selecting using `array[..., 1:]`. Thanks again for the thorough answer, I learned a whole lot of new Numpy functions today!

Comment: @wvdkamp. Thanks for the catch and glad you liked it :)

Answer (score 3):

If you do not care about the output order then [`array.partition(1)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.partition.html#numpy.ndarray.partition), `array.sort()` and `np.sort(array)` are fastest. On a 10K random matrix `array.sort()` wins by a small margin.`array[..., 1:]` will contain the results. This is interesting because one might expect that `partition()` is somewhat faster than `sort()`.

```
Python 3.7, Numpy 1.16.5, with MKL
----------------------------------
array.partition : 5.57 s
np.sort         : 5.15 s
array.sort      : 5.02 s
```

If order is important credits go to Mad Physicist's `numpy.put_along_axis` solution. My previously suggested solution is about twice as slow as this:

```
ind = array.argpartition(1)[..., 1:]
ind.sort()
np.take_along_axis(array, ind, -1)
```

Comment: The limiting factor here is that the third dimension is 3. Both partition and sort use median lookup to handle that case. Partition just has more overhead.

Comment: Great answer that gives the correct answer and is very fast.